# How to get the last record of every 24 hours in mysql?

Tags: mysql

In the following table, I want to return every last records of last 24 hours span. Also taking consider if place_id is not present then return second last record which has place_id. In following table for `NULL, '2016-04-06 18:52:06'` record we are returning `'13664', '2016-04-06 12:57:30'`, which is second last record in 24 hours and has place_id.

```
   id  ||  place_id || date
   '1',   '47', '2016-04-05 18:09:37'
   '2',   '48', '2016-04-05 12:09:37'
   '3',   '13664', '2016-04-06 12:57:30'
   '4',   '9553', '2016-04-08 10:09:37'
   '5',   NULL, '2016-04-06 18:52:06'
   '6',   '9537', '2016-04-07 03:34:24'
   '7',   '9537', '2016-04-07 03:34:24'
   '8',   '656', '2016-04-07 05:34:24'
   '9',   '7', '2016-04-07 05:34:57'
```

When I run following query it returns following result

**Query** I change the query but it is giving me NULL

```
select S1.place_id, S1.date from 
     status TTS1 
Left join
     status TTS2
on 
     Date(S1.date) = Date(S2.date)
And
    S1.date < S2.date
where 
    S2.date is null and S1.location_id=38298

group by S1.date;
```

**Result**

```
'47', '2016-04-05 18:09:37'
NULL, '2016-04-06 18:52:06'
'7', '2016-04-07 05:34:57'
'9553', '2016-04-08 10:09:37'
```

But This result is not correct, It is give `NULL`, If there is NULL then return the second last entry on that day..

**Correct Result:**

```
'47', '2016-04-05 18:09:37'    
'13664', '2016-04-06 12:57:30'
'9553', '2016-04-08 10:09:37'
'7', '2016-04-07 05:34:57'
```

Comment: @Strawberry I  have primary Key, But right now I am showing only partial table,  I change the query now, please look at my modified query..

Comment: @Strawberry, Here I have taken Primary key is automatic increment ..

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks I updated..

Comment: @Strawberry, sorry I mistaken insert duplicate record, It will not come in result, but result will be `'9',   '7', '2016-04-07 05:34:57'`, which is coming, I am  only concern about how to take second last record if place_id is null in 24 hours time span..

Comment: Surely your `group by S1.date;` will include the time too? So you would need `GROUP BY DATE(S1.date);` then add a condition to filter out `place_id IS NOT NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select distinct  s.place_id, s.date from base_status s 
where s.locatoin_id=38298 group by Date(s.date) order by s.date DESC;
```

Comment: you posted my same query, `order by s.date DESC;` will not effect on result.

Comment: please provide sql fiddle so that i can test it

Comment: Wasiq, with or without a fiddle, I don't think this approach is going to work

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works :

```
select s.*
from (SELECT s.place_id, max(s.date) as maxdate
      FROM base_status s
      GROUP BY place_id 
     ) ss join
     base_status s
     on ss.place_id = s.place_id and ss.maxdate = s.date;
```

Comment: We can't use group by place_id, because it may be possible that on second day place_id will be same ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` in this case. I suppose you haven't given the complete schema information here. So may be I am missing some fields.

The following query returns your desired result set:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `status` 
WHERE date IN
    (
        SELECT MAX(s.date)
        FROM `status` s
        WHERE IFNULL(s.place_id,'') <> ''
        GROUP BY CAST(s.date AS DATE)
    )
```

**Explanation:**
You don't need self join here. The logic is to `Group By Date` and then get the `Maximum DateTime record`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MAX(date) max_date 
         FROM my_table 
        WHERE place_id IS NOT NULL 
        GROUP 
           BY DATE(date)
     ) y 
    ON y.max_date = x.date;
```

I still think you have a problem where the max value is not unique.